# What are ways to imbue magic into a cloth armour?

Tags: dnd-4e, armor

In the PHB1, this is said about cloth armour:

> Jackets, woven robes, and padded vests don't, by themselves, provide any significant protection. However, you can imbue them with protective magic.

Yet I couldn't find an expanation on how to imbue magic into an armour in my books. How can it be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Enchant Magic Item**

You're looking for the [Enchant Magic Item](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=9) ritual in the Player's handbook, which allows you to enchant basically any common item (except for potions). This means you can make boring +X cloth armor, but few of the specialised things like the [Robe of Eyes](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2281).

An explanation of the updated magic item rarity rules (that replace the daily item use rules) can be found [here](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/drfe/20100824)

In the rules compendium, under [magic item rarity](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=670), we get:

> Uncommon and rare magic items are not normally created in the current age of the world. ... Now they are found only as part of treasure hoards in ancient ruins and dangerous dungeons.

Between the two sources, it is clear that only common items can be crafted, though that sentence does not specifically occur in the text. Furthermore, considering the consequences of removing daily item use limits *without* enforcing item rarity, all sorts of broken possibilities are found.

Here is a comprehensive list of what kind of cloth armor you *can* enchant with that ritual, and the ritual caster feat:

> ```
> Magic Armor                    Armor  1+  360+ gp     Common  Multiple Sources
> Agile Resolve Vestments        Armor  2+  520+ gp     Common  Player's Handbook 2
> Armor of Cleansing             Armor  3+  680+ gp     Common  Multiple Sources
> Armor of Escape                Armor  2+  520+ gp     Common  Mordenkainen's Magnificent Emporium
> Armor of Resistance            Armor  2+  520+ gp     Common  Adventurer's Vault
> Astral Fire Armor              Armor  2+  520+ gp     Common  Player's Handbook 2
> Haunted Armor                  Armor  2+  520+ gp     Common  Dragon Magazine 400
> Indomitable Resolve Vestments  Armor  2+  520+ gp     Common  Player's Handbook 2
> Robe of Useful Items           Armor  2+  520+ gp     Common  Mordenkainen's Magnificent Emporium
> Slick Armor                    Armor  2+  520+ gp     Common  Adventurer's Vault
> Veteran's Armor                Armor  2+  520+ gp     Common  Multiple Sources
> Sylvan Armor                   Armor  3+  680+ gp     Common  Multiple Sourceslt
> Darkleaf Armor                 Armor  4+  840+ gp     Common  Player's Handboo
> Tactician's Armor              Armor  5+  1,000+ gp   Common  Adventurer's Vauk
> Wildleaf Armor                 Armor  17+ 65,000+ gp  Common  Adventurer's Vault
> Perpetual Resolve Vestments    Armor  20+ 125,000+ gp Common  Player's Handbook 2
> ```

Comment: My reading of the ritual suggests no limit on what items you can enchant. "You touch a normal item and turn it into a magic item of your level or lower." No restriction to common items.